# Don't include self answered or questions where the OP commented in the review audits

Tags: feature-request, review, review-audits

There is a mayor problem with one of our close reasons and the audits. We close stuff based in "no reproducible" basis, when OP can't figure out what was wrong nor how the issue was solved nor there's enough diagnostic information to verify, or simply OP gave up. Now, those issues somehow or another get several upvotes and when we try to close it due the comment we fail.

Example: https://askubuntu.com/review/close/235631

I see only 2 solutions:

- Don't include in the audit such questions
- Obscure OP comments on the audit